# Mysql exists operator not working correctly or there is any other problem?

Tags: mysql, exists

I have two tables

- txn_maxvoucherno (companycode, dbcode, vouchertype, fyear, series, voucherno)
- txn_vouchersdetails (voucherno, vouchertype)

I am executing a stored procedure to generate new voucher no in `txn_maxvoucherno` table, which is `max(voucherno)+1`, then I check in `txn_vouchersdetails` for an entry to exists in this table if it exists it will again increment the `voucherno` by 1 and check again. This happens three times. so there three attempts to find `voucherno` every time by incrementing one before throwing an error.

The problem is it always go inside first if condition even if the voucher no does not exists in the table or exists in the table.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spGenerateVoucherNo`(in companyCode int, IN dbCode int, in vouType nvarchar(10), IN Fyear int, IN series int, IN VoucherNo int, OUT NewVoucherNo INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(VoucherNo) INTO NewVoucherNo from txn_maxvoucherno
    WHERE CompanyCode = companyCode AND DBCode = dbCode AND VoucherType = vouType
    GROUP BY VoucherType;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from txn_vouchersdetails WHERE VoucherNo = NewVoucherNo AND VoucherType like vouType) then
    BEGIN
        SET NewVoucherNo = NewVoucherNo + 1;
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from txn_vouchersdetails WHERE VoucherNo = NewVoucherNo AND VoucherType like vouType) then
        BEGIN
            SET NewVoucherNo = NewVoucherNo + 1;
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from txn_vouchersdetails WHERE VoucherNo = NewVoucherNo AND VoucherType like vouType) then
            BEGIN
                /* Return Error */
                SET NewVoucherNo = -1;
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Issue on server. Please try after some time.';
            END;
            END IF;
        END;
        END IF;
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

The table data are as below
txn_maxvoucherno:

```
companyCode DBCode  VoucherType FYear   Series  VoucherNo

1   1   SAL 2022    1   1
```

txn_vouchersdetails:

```
VoucherNo   VoucherType

1   SAL
2   SAL
3   SAL
```

Comment: why do you use like operator without a wildcard? it is a comparison but with an overhead for the query to execute

Comment: i was just trying to execute the query in different ways to get the result, but it is always hitting inside first exists and never going in second if block even if record exists. I tried using equal to also.

Comment: This is just bad. You don't need the separate table. The main table will tell you the max voucher number with a simple query. You should probably use an auto-increment for the number. Or you can use a transaction or locking to ensure it doesn't get incremented in another thread. Or at least use a loop.